# Modelling a graph like entity relationship in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, graph-databases

I have a project tracking application. The app has the following entities:

1. project
2. story - belong to a particular project
3. user - belong to a particular project, assigned to a particular story

Each `project` can have multiple `story` and `user` entities as descendants. Each `story` can be parent to multiple `user` entities. Basically, every project has several users that can work on the various stories (tasks) within the project. Each story can have multiple users assigned to it as well. Something like below:

[image]

Now my question is, can i model such a relationship in the app engine datastore using ancestor queries without causing an index explosion? For example, i can find out stories within a project with a simple query. But to find out stories assigned to a specific user would require traversing the entire story index (which isn't really an issue due to query performance being independent of index table size), but would it not be better to have the query reflect a graph like relationship here? As if modeled using a graph database like neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user can work on multiple stories, or none at the moment, and/or can ever change the story they're working on (get assigned to a different story later), then modeling the story as "parent" to the user seems deeply wrong on a semantic level -- it may also cause performance issues (depending on kind of queries, frequency of reads and writes, etc, etc), but, that's quite a secondary worry, I'd focus on the semantic correctness first and I'm not entirely sure about the specific semantics of your data model.

A parent "relationship", in GAE's datastore, is intended to model a persistent (actually I'd say "permanent", in terms of the child entity's lifetime:-) 1:many connection -- especially one that may well require transactional behavior (or even just strong consistency) among parent and child, or among siblings (transactional behavior and strong consistency don't come for free, performance-wise -- but, when you need them, you really need them:-).  How well does the connection between story and user in your app match this summary?

There are of course other ways you can model persistent 1:many connections; using `ndb` concepts, a `StructuredProperty` can in fact let you **embed** the "child" entity "inside" the "parent" one (and if you don't need queries on the child's attributes you can gain a speed boost by using the **local** kind of structured property).

And of course, the most general way to model any kind of relationship is with `KeyProperty` -- that doesn't require the relationship to be persistent/permanent, nor necessarily 1:many (e.g if a user can be assigned to multiple stories).  In fact you can view key properties as edges in a directed graph where entities are the nodes, with full generality (indeed it can be a **multi** directed-graph, with 0+ edges from node A to node B, if you need even more generality than a "mere" graph can provide:-).  But of course you can pay some price for such broad generality, if you don't really need it nor use it.

In the end, beyond complete clarity in the entity-relationship modeling (which is a good thing no matter what kind of db is underlying:-), the choice of "schema" (in the broadest sense of the word:-) for a NoSQL database is strongly dependent on what queries, updates, &c, the app will require, with what frequency, tolerance for latency, transactionality requisites, consistency (strong vs eventual), ... to a higher degree than for the relational databases that are what I think most of us "cut our teeth on".  Thus I would encourage you to strive to make both aspects very explicit -- the E-R layer of abstraction, of course, but **also** the mix of queries, updates, &c, and the constraints and desiderata on them.

Comment: Thanks. So the app engine ancestors queries are mainly to enforce consistency. You are right in saying that there really is no parent -> child relationship here. Just possible 1:Many relationships that would change a lot. `StructuredProperty` might not work as each embedded entity is required as a separate model. I do believe the `KeyProperty` idea would suit the application best.

Comment: (cont.) However, this would affect the queries adversely, as > 1 fetches (and writes) might be needed to completely follow relationships. Also, there would be a need of some de-normalization. This is turning out to be a hard one :). (sorry about the very late reply :) )

Comment: @abhink, agreed on the likely need for some denorm to optimize performance (depending on the mix of queries, updates, &c, which I encourage you to make very explicit!-) -- that's a typical issue with all NoSQL databases, and it's most of the price you pay for their scalability and efficiency.  If, as you say, relationships "can change a lot", then you either do use KeyProperty (+ possibly some denorm), or, resign yourself to a lot of copying when such changes occur (creating a wholly new entity copying the old one w/a different parent, deleting the old one)...